# How to format String xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx in Postgres

Tags: sql, postgresql, string-formatting

e.g I have string cardNo = `1111111111111111` (16 digits)

I want to format cardNo by add dash (-) per 4 digits:

```
1111-1111-1111-1111
```

Comment: Don't just stick random databases in as tags. Please pick a specific one that your problem relates to.

Comment: Saving bare card numbers directly into a database, is not a standard practice. Instead encrypt the card number and store the hash string into database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using Postgres, you can take advantage of the `regexp_replace()` function:

```
SELECT regexp_replace(t.col::text, '(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})(\d{4})', '\1-\2-\3-\4', 'g')
FROM
(
    SELECT 1111111111111111 AS col
) t
```

Here, we match and capture the 16 digits in four groups, then build the replacement with dashes per your requirements.

If you are using MySQL, which doesn't have this type of regex replacement support, you'll have to use the base string functions:

```
SELECT CONCAT(SUBSTRING(col, 1, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(col, 5, 4), '-',
              SUBSTRING(col, 9, 4), '-', SUBSTRING(col, 13, 4))
FROM yourTable
```